# C# program to remote login and change password of services

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am required to write a C# program, that, given a list of servers and services running on them, remotely logs into the servers, stops the service, changes the password associated with that service and restarts the service.

I am not entirely sure if it is even possible, but I would like to believe it is. Any pointers as to where / what I should be looking at to get started?

PS - I am not limited to C#. If there is another language that would make this task easier, Ia m open to suggestions.

Comment: PowerShell is a scripting language that kicks butt when it comes to this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use **WMI** to accomplish all of these operations you mentioned. **WMI** is exposed through `System.Manangement.Instrumentation` and there are plenty of examples out there, just google C#+WMI.

Another option is to use `ServiceController` class which you can use to also remotely connect to services but not sure if you can change the credentials of the service (its identity) with it.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence of [OpenSCManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684323%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [OpenService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684330%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [ChangeServiceConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681987%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) can be used to modify the password or anything else you want to modify, given sufficient access permissions on the target machines.

I imagine native code is just as easy as wrapping this in C# and using P/Invoke, but it might be worth your while to do it that way depending on how you have to handle the target server list.

EDIT:

If you are using WMI per the other answer, you will need to use [Win32_Service class Change method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384901%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: 1+ for mentioning the WMI class.

Comment: @Aliostad - very gracious -  I already upvoted your superior suggestion